# Transparent navigation bar not working (comes out translucent blue)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to have a transparent Navigation bar for all my view controllers.

I have done this in my navigation controller -

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

But for some reason I am getting a very light translucent blue?! Any ideas? I can simply change the colour correctly but for some reason this is coming out blueish...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the navigation view background color and the navigation bar background color too.

```
        navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true
        navigationController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```